# Query table with no grant?

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, privileges

If I'm creating a table in user A.

How user B can query that table if I didn't gave it any privs?

In that code, I'm creating table general.privs_test from DBA user named "DBA_MAINT".

After that, I'm switching to another user and try to query the table.

There is no exception, even there is no grant on that table.

```
SQL> select user from dual;

USER
------------------------------
DBA_MAINT

SQL> create table general.privs_test(id number);

Table created.

SQL> conn dp99712a
Enter password:
Connected.
SQL> select user from dual;

USER
------------------------------
DP99712A

SQL> select * from general.privs_test;

no rows selected

SQL> desc all_tab_privs;
 Name                                      Null?    Type
 ----------------------------------------- -------- ----------------------------

 GRANTOR                                   NOT NULL VARCHAR2(30)
 GRANTEE                                   NOT NULL VARCHAR2(30)
 TABLE_SCHEMA                              NOT NULL VARCHAR2(30)
 TABLE_NAME                                NOT NULL VARCHAR2(30)
 PRIVILEGE                                 NOT NULL VARCHAR2(40)
 GRANTABLE                                          VARCHAR2(3)
 HIERARCHY                                          VARCHAR2(3)

SQL> select grantee,table_schema,table_name,privilege, grantable from all_tab_pr
ivs where table_name = 'PRIVS_TEST';

no rows selected
```

My version is ORacle 11g.

Comment: The user has `select any table` role granted? Or the grant is done via role. Check `user_role_privs`and `user_sys_privs`.

Comment: Have a look at views `USER_ROLE_PRIVS`, `USER_SYS_PRIVS`, `USER_TAB_PRIVS`

Answer (score 2):

As the table is freshly created without any privileges, the user dp99712a must have a system privilege that lets see him/her all tables. This privilege is called `SELECT ANY TABLE` and is granted normally to the role `DBA`.

To find out if this is the case, connect as user dp99712a  and query:

```
SELECT * FROM session_privs WHERE PRIVILEGE = 'SELECT ANY TABLE';
```

To find out all the users and roles that have this privilege, you can use:

```
SELECT DISTINCT grantee
  FROM dba_sys_privs 
 WHERE PRIVILEGE LIKE 'SELECT ANY TABLE%' ORDER BY 1;
```